# Completely positive maps and abelian C* algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

This is a problem I encountered in Jesse Peterson's Notes on Von Neumann Algebras. I want to show the following: given C* algebra A, suppose for any C* algebra B, every positive map from B to A is completely positive, then A is an abelian C* algebra.

I have no idea how to show this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

See

*Tomiyama, Jun*, [**On the difference of n-positivity and complete positivity in C*-algebras**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-1236(82)90083-0), J. Funct. Anal. 49, 1-9 (1982). [ZBL0497.46039](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0497.46039).

Comment: Thank you very much.